# Storing Data into a Linked List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

The input is in the following format.

```
    5
    1 2  9.0
    1 3 12.0
    2 4 18.0
    2 3  6.0
    2 5 20.0
    3 5 15.0
    0
    1 5
```

The first number is the number of vertexes in the graph. Then next lines up to 0 are the edges of the graph. With the first and second numbers being the vertexes and the third being how far the edge is between them. I can not figure out how to store the data into the List adjacency for each of the vertexes when reading it in. EX. Vertex 1 would have two List cells containing 2 9.0 and 3 12.0. I would also need to put the 1 9.0 and 1 12.0 into vertexes 2 and 3. But I can not figure out how to store the data into the ListCells

Code so Far:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
typedef ListCell* List;

struct ListCell
{
   ListCell* next;
   int vertex;
   double weight;

   ListCell(int v, double w, ListCell* nxt)
   {
      vertex = v;
      weight = w;
      next = nxt;
   }
};

struct Vertex
{
   bool signaled;
   long distance;
   Vertex next;
   List adjacency;    
};

struct Graph
{
   int     numVertices;
   Vertex* vertexInfo;

   Graph(int n)
   {
      numVertices = n;
      vertexInfo  = new Vertex[n+1];
      for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      {
         vertexInfo[i].signaled = false;
      }
   }
};

//==============================================================
//                   readIn
//==============================================================
// 
//==============================================================

void readIn()
{
   int n, p1, p2;
   double edge;
   scanf("%i ", &n);

   Graph(n);
   while(scanf("%i " &p1) != 0)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: OK, good, feel free to carry on...

Comment: Maybe you should move the input functionality into the `Graph` class?

Answer (score 0):

I use to define data structures in a way suitable for the business logic.

I would suggest you have a look on [The Art of Computer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) to have an idea of some best practices.

Put an eye on "Linear Lists" chapter

hint:
 traverse the list and append the new node (please take care of corner cases):

```
Vertex* v = vertexInfo[i];
while (v->next!=null) {
   v = v->next;
}
v->next = new Vertex(....);
```